# Firefox add-on to display iFrame

Tags: firefox, iframe, firefox-addon

I'm trying to create firefox addon which will add an icon near the address bar, and when the user will click it, it will show an iframe which I'll set.
Something similiar to chrome extension, as like this:

http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/images/hello-world.png

Thanks

Comment: ou need to be a little more specific as to what you need help with.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an overlaying method.

Article : [Creating toolbar button](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Creating_toolbar_buttons) @ MDC

XUL of popup box can refer to `notification-popup` and `identity-popup`(suggested) at **chrome://browser/content/browser.xul**

And iframe is avaiable in XUL.

```
<panel id="sth-popup" type="arrow" hidden="true" noautofocus="true" onpopupshown="(initial action)" level="top">
    <iframe id="sth-body" src="chrome://(extenstion name)/(sth html)" flex="1"/>
</panel>
```

For the listeners (onclick, onkeypress) of toolbar button , please refers to `gIdentityHandler . handleIdentityButtonEvent`at **chrome://browser/content/browser.js**

---

If your addon is a bootstrapped extension, please refers to [Playing with windows in restartless (bootstrapped) extensions](http://www.oxymoronical.com/blog/2011/01/Playing-with-windows-in-restartless-bootstrapped-extensions) at Oxymoronical.

Javascript DOM control technique is required.

Refers to the XUL example and create the elements simply by `document.createElement` method or even by`document.createElementNS(XULNS, "(tag name)")` method, where`const XULNS = 'http://www.mozilla.org/keymaster/gatekeeper/there.is.only.xul';` had been written.

---

Feel free to ask more and to be one of our registered users. **:-)**

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is with the creation of the iframe? or with creating the iframe content? (for instance u can't set a src attribute to a file which is not the domain of the page where u want to display the iframe)